# Child processes not sharing parents cgroup

Tags: cgroups

I am a newbie in using cgroup. I am managing cgroups using libcgroup on CentOS 64. I have managed to create some cgroups e.g.

```
[ehsan.haq@datavault ~]$ cgcreate -g blkio:/test
[ehsan.haq@datavault ~]$ cgcreate -g cpu:/test
```

Lets say, I have a parent process `125672` and its child processes `33117, 33403, 33404, 33880, 34663`

```
[ehsan.haq@datavault ~]$ pgrep -P 125672
33117
33403
33404
33880
34663
```

What I want is to move the parent process `125672` and its existing children `33117, 33403, 33404, 33880, 34663` and also future children `?,?,?` in the cgroups `blkio:/test` and `cpu:/test`. What is the correct way to achieve this?

I have tried

```
cgclassify -g blkio:/test [--sticky] 125672
cgclassify -g cpu:/test [--sticky] 125672
```

but the `cgroup.procs` and `tasks` file only contains the parent process id only.

```
[ehsan.haq@datavault ~]$ cat /cgroup/blkio/test/cgroup.procs
125672
[ehsan.haq@datavault ~]$ cat /cgroup/blkio/test/tasks
125672
```

Does it mean that the child process are not in the parents cgroup? if not then how should I do it.

### Update

I found out that instead of using `cgclassify`, if I do

```
echo "{parent PID}" > /cgroup/blkio/test/tasks
```

then all the future children processes also ends up in the `/cgroup/blkio/test/cgroup.procs`

Comment: You should also be able to use the `--sticky` option to `cgclassify`. In any case, if you solved your problem yourself, consider adding it as an answer.